Drag forces and Lorentz covariance
I am looking for a simple example where a drag force on a macroscopic body moving in a fluid is derived from a microscopic model.
I am not so much interested in a realistic model but in a Lorentz-covariant derivation, e.g. based on averaging over microscopic degrees of freedom, collisions etc.
For a large body of mass $M$ I am expecting a replacement of
$$ M \frac{d\mathbf{u}}{dt} = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u}) $$
like
$$ M \frac{du^\mu}{d\tau} = F^\mu(u^\mu) $$
where $u^\mu$ and $F^\mu$ are 4-velocity and 4-drag-force, respectively.
I guess that the fluid (liquid, gas) somehow defines a specific rest frame and therefore dynamically breaks Lorentz covariance. I am interested how this works in detail, starting from a manifest Lorentz covariant microscopic model.
I think there should be applications in astrophysics, e.g. high energetic cosmic radiation moving through interstellar media.

Search for derivations of the Langevin equation for a particle in thermally fluctuating medium. The derivation is lengthy and easiest in the frame of the medium, which is the preferred frame. Translating it to formalism of four-vectors and four-tensors may be possible, but it will complicate the derivation. It's much easier to solve equations in the preferred frame, and then transform the motion into any other frame desired.
